# Jquery menu doesnt open on touch screen devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a drop down menu where the user selects a location and it scrolls to the div to reveal the address (10 different locations).

This works well in a desktop browser. However on the ipad, iphone and nexus it doesnt work because of touch screen.

This is my code:-

```
<html>
  <div class="location">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Select an Office</a>
      <ul class="officeselect">
        <li><a data-emailaddress="" data-address='<span class="address">99 Walnut Tree Close</span>
        <span class="address">Guildford</span>
        <span class="address">Surrey</span>
        <span class="address">GU1 4UQ</span><br>
        <span class="address">T: +44 1483 881500</span>
        <span class="address"><a href="mailto:info@petroplan.com">info@petroplan.com</a></span>' href="">UK Head</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="span4 alpha">
  <div class="addresstitle">
    <h3>Address</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="address">
  </div>
</div>

</html>



<script>
// Scroll down to map and address function
$(".location ul li ul a").click(updateAddressDisplay);

function updateAddressDisplay(src) {

  $('.office-sel-cont .chooser').text($(this).text());

  var target = $(".address");
  var source;
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
  }, 1000);

  if (src === null)
    source = $(".black-sectors li a.adr-src:eq(0)");
  else
    source = $(this);

  target.fadeOut();
  target.html(source.data("address") + source.data("emailaddress"));
  target.fadeIn();

  var chooser = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.chooser');

  if (chooser.hasClass('open')) {
    chooser.removeClass('open');
    chooser.next($('.black-sectors')).animate({
      'top': '60px',
      'opacity': 0
    }, 600, 'easeOutQuint', function() {
      chooser.next($('.black-sectors')).toggle();
    });
    return false;
  } else {

  }

  return false;
}
</script>
```

And I used this below from this website, but it's still dodgy.

```
<script>
$('.location ul li ul a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var el = $(this);
  var link = el.attr('href');
  window.location = link;
});
</script>
```

Thanks for your help.

this is the fiddle:-http://jsfiddle.net/ScVs9/

Comment: This is the fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/ScVs9/

Answer (score 0):

For your drop down list to work on a touch screen device you need to trigger the drop-down using a javascript click event rather than the css hover. Simple way would be create a class, called something like `.active` and then use a function like this:

```
$('.location a').on('click', function(){
    $('.officeselect').toggleClass('active')
});
```

The active class would simply have visibility set to visible:

```
ul.officeselect.active {visibility:visible;}
```

The user should then be able to select the correct link and display the address as per usual.

I hope this helps